# 'this' inside nested objects (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I would like to have some object structure like this (which I know that's not possible)

```
const AUTH = {
    base: 'auth',
    login: {
        enter: `${AUTH.base}/login`,
        password: `${AUTH.base}/login/password`,
    },
}
```

EDIT: I also want to export the object as a module

So I did some experiences

**Experience A**

```js
const AUTH_BASE = 'auth'
const AUTH_A = {
  login: {
    enter: `${AUTH_BASE}/login`,
    password: `${AUTH_BASE}/login/password`,
  }
}

console.log('enter ->', AUTH_A.login.enter)
console.log('recover ->', AUTH_A.login.password)
```

Experience A output:

```
enter -> auth/login
recover -> auth/login/password
```

**Experience B**

```js
const AUTH_B = {
  base: 'auth',
  login() {
    return `${this.base}/login`
  },
  password() {
    return `${this.base}/login/password`
  },
}

console.log('enter ->', AUTH_B.login())
console.log('recover ->', AUTH_B.password())
```

Experience B output:

```
enter -> auth/login
recover -> auth/login/password
```

**Experience C**

```js
const AUTH_C = {
  base1: 'auth',
  login: {
    base2: 'auth????????????????',
    enter1: function() {
      return `${this.base1}/login`
    },
    enter2: function() {
      return `${this.base2}/login`
    },
    password: function() {
      return `${this.base}/login/password`
    },
  }
}

console.log('enter 1 ->', AUTH_C.login.enter1())
console.log('enter 2 ->', AUTH_C.login.enter2())
console.log('recover ->', AUTH_C.login.password())
```

Experience C output:

```
enter 1 -> undefined/login
enter 2 -> auth????????????????/login
recover -> undefined/login/password
```

**Experience D**

```js
const AUTH_D = {
  base: 'auth',
  login: {},
}

AUTH_D.login = {
  enter: `${AUTH_D.base}/login`,
  password: `${AUTH_D.base}/login/password`,
}

console.log('enter ->', AUTH_D.login.enter)
console.log('recover ->', AUTH_D.login.password)
```

Experience D output:

```
enter -> auth/login
recover -> auth/login/password
```

My question is: there is any better way to achieve my desired syntax?

repl.it link: https://repl.it/@SandroMiguel/Endpoints-constants-experience

Comment: you can also use a factory function which will take auth base and return object you want

Comment: This is subjective, to me, the option A looks the best.

Comment: **Experience B** seems good. Since it would be like a single object which your can export it as a module as well.

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a static class like this :

```
class Auth {
  static base = 'auth'
  static login = {
    enter: `${Auth.base}/login`
  }
}
```

Or use getters to self-references the object

```
const AUTH = {
  base: 'auth',
  get login() {
    return {
      enter: `${AUTH.base}/login`,
      password: `${AUTH.base}/login/password`
    }
  }
}
```

So you can access your properties like any others props :

```
console.log(AUTH.login.enter)
console.log(AUTH.login.password)
```

Answer (score 0):

In comment i'm talking about this :

```
function authFactory(base){
    this.base = base;
    this.login = {
        enter: `${base}/login`,
        password: `${base}/login/password`
    }
}

const AUTH_E = new authFactory("auth");
console.log('enter E ->', AUTH_E.login.enter);
console.log('recover E ->', AUTH_E.login.password);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best method to achieve what you want is this

```js
const AUTH_B = {
    base: 'auth',
    login() {
        return `${this.base}/login`
    },
    password() {
        return `${this.base}/login/password`
    },
}
Object.freeze(AUTH_B);
AUTH_B.base = "something_else";
console.log(AUTH_B.login())
```

Because the object property is now frozen inside and cannot be edited from outside and will not affect others.

To export this as a module create a file named `module.js` and paste this inside

```
const AUTH_B = {
    base: 'auth',
    login() {
        return `${this.base}/login`
    },
    password() {
        return `${this.base}/login/password`
    },
}
Object.freeze(AUTH_B);
AUTH_B.base = "something_else";

exports.AUTH_B = AUTH_B; // export your object like this
```

Now open your index.js and do

```
var m = require('./module.js'); // access it like m.AUTH_B
console.log(m.AUTH_B.login()); // gives -> auth/login
```

### [Example](https://repl.it/repls/ElementaryLegitimateGraphs)